# How to make a toggle that triggers a alert in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to fix it and I looked at the other questions but I couldn’t find any good answers.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showGreeting = true
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Dont Do!", isOn: $showGreeting)
            
            .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            if showGreeting {
                showingAlert = true
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't behaving as you expect? What is the issue? What errors or warnings are you getting?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the two bindings.  If you want the toggle to show the alert, you need to bind them to the same property, so that when the toggle turns it to `true` the alert shows.   You also have some other issues, including a the random '`if` statement in the view builder.  Did you mean this to be in the alert's action?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a button is probably more suitable than a toggle for an action that can only be turned off (in this case you're just flipping the switch back on again, so why not use a button?).

If you use a button this becomes easier because you can just use one Binding var, showingAlert and set that to true when the button is pressed.

*However,* I went ahead with the implementation you started with. I just threw in some .onChange modifiers which look for changes to State variables. In this case, we're looking for changes to either of your two State vars and then setting the other one appropriately when a change does come through.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showGreeting = true
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Dont Do!", isOn: $showGreeting)
                .alert(Text("Important Message"), isPresented: $showingAlert, actions: { 
                    Button("OK") { }
                })

                // newValue comes from the onChange modifier... 
                // You can call it anything, really, but newValue 
                // is verbose enough for this case
                .onChange(of: showGreeting, perform: { newValue in
                    showingAlert = !newValue
                })
                .onChange(of: showingAlert, perform: { newValue in
                    showGreeting = !newValue
                })
        }
    }
}
```